# How to use a variable within a regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, variables

I have a regular expression and would like to put a variable inside it. How do I do?

My code is this:

```js
public regexVariable(vRegex: string, testSentences: Array<any> ) {
    const regex = new RegExp('/^.*\b(' + vRegex + ')\b.*$/');
    const filterSentece = testSentences.filter(result => {
        if (regex.test(result)) {
            return result
        })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Don't forget to escape your backslashes in the string literal and remove the leading/trailing forward slashes.

Comment: A word of caution The '.*' at the beginning of the regex may not be what you intend it to be. As Regexes are greedy by default it has a high chance of capturing to much. So if you run in any problems try using '.*?' instead of '.*' to get non greedy behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const regex = new RegExp(`^.*\\b(${vRegex})\\b.*$`);
```

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`` ` ``, instead of `"`/`'`) to build strings that you can interpolate expresions into; no more oldschool `+`ing.

The only thing that was an actual issue with your code, though, was the `\b` character class. This sequence is what you want `RegExp` to see, but you can't just write that, otherwise you're sending `RegExp` the *[backspace character](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#single)*.
You need to write `\\b`, which as you can see from that link, will make a string with a `\` and an ordinary `b` for *[`RegExp` to interpret](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)*.

Comment: Even better: `String.raw\`^.*\b${vRegex}\b.*$\``. Also don't forget to explain why you changed the things you did.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just look at [RegEx constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
const regex = new RegExp('^.*\\b(' + vRegex + ')\\b.*$');
```